# LESSC source maps not working

Tags: css, less

I'm running lessc as following:

```
lessc alice/public/local/less/intfarm.less > alice/public/local/css/local/compiled/intfarm.css --source-map=alice/public/local/less/intfarm.map --verbose
```

the source map is output but it doesn't work. I check the file and at the end I read:

...

```
,iBAAA;EACA,cAAA;;AA1EZ,IAAI,SA8EA;EACI,gBAAA","file":"../../../../undefined
```

do I need to set other flags as well? 
(shoutout at LESS creators: why not enable this by default and save us hours of work and searching?)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `>` between your source and destiny. In fact your send the output to `stdout`. The compiler don't know that you are writing the output to intfarm.css and so can not construct the source map link to that file.

Also see: https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/2389

Comment: what should I use instead? Could you correct my command please?

Comment: `lessc alice/public/local/less/intfarm.less  alice/public/local/css/local/compiled/intfarm.css --source-map=alice/public/local/less/intfarm.map --verbose` because of: `usage: lessc [option option=parameter ...] <source> [destination]` so set the destination instead of a redirect

Answer (score 0):

another solution can be using **--source-map-map-inline** parameter instead of **--source-map=...** but I think the best solution is the one pointed by Bass Jobsen